# Converting 4 character hex string to a signed short with string streams in c++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

A similar question has been asked before, and I am using the solution from that question, but it isn't working 100%.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string hexStr1 = "ffff";
    short s1;
    stringstream ss1;
    ss1 << hex << hexStr1;
    ss1 >> s1;

    string hexStr2 = "f";
    short s2;
    stringstream ss2;
    ss2 << hex << hexStr2;
    ss2 >> s2;

    s2 = s2 | -16;



    cout << "s1: " << s1 << "\n";  //Outputs 32767 (max short)
    cout << "s2: " << s2 << "\n";  //Outputs -1 
}
```

Shouldn't the value stored in `s1` be `-1` because if a (2-byte) short variable has the value `0xffff` it would be negative one?

I don't see what is different about how I'm setting s2 vs. how I'm setting s1, but the results are different...

I would like the program above to print out:

```
s1: -1
s2: -1
```

Can anyone explain why the value in s1 is not -1 after my program runs?

Comment: `0xffff` can't fit in a `signed short`.  Overflowing a singed integer is undefined behavior so any result is "correct"

Comment: I don't have to use string stream, but I would like to.  I believed that a signed short was 16 bits in size, why would '0xffff' not fit in it?

Comment: The max value of a 16 bit signed short is `0x7fff`.  Anything more than that will overflow.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Extracting from a stream has different specified behaviour than native operations. IIRC, streams (rather, the default facet that deals with this) always set it to the max value in this case. That said, I strongly believe initializing a signed integral type with a value over the max is IB (specifically, an implementation-defined value) rather than UB, as well as for assignment.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there is no signed short overload for `std::num_get::get()`.  The stream extraction `operator>>(short&)` is actually reading 0xffff from the string as an long int, failing to convert the value to a short because of potential overlfow, assigning a defined value of `std::numeric_limits<short>::max()` and setting `std::ios_base::failbit` on the stream.

See ISO/IEC 14882 [istream.formatted.arithmetic]/2 for a detailed description of this well-defined and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is that

```
ss1 >> hex >> s1;
```

fails. It does for me.

Update the code to add a check.

```
if ( !(ss1 >> hex >> s1) )
{
   cout << "Unable to read s1\n";
}
```

If reading into `s1` fails, it does not make sense to rely on its value until it has been set to something valid.